# can't make bool function c++

Tags: c++, function, boolean

Question is:

> Check if a number is prime.
>
> When the user selects this option in `switch`, the program asks the user to enter an integer, then passes it to a function called `isPrime`. `isPrime` is a function which takes an integer as a parameter and returns true if the parameter is a prime number, and false otherwise.

In file (.h) prototype is

```
void isPrime ( int y )
```

---

I think the error I'm getting is because of the type of the function.

```
void isPrime(int num)
{
    bool prime = true;
    int i = 2;
    {
        if (num == 2)
            cout << prime;
    }
    while (i <= num - 1)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            cout << false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (i == num)
        cout << prime;
}
```

---

### only positive numbers

I worte the code in a
another way but again
it doesn't work ?

---

```
bool isPrime ( int num )
{
bool prime = true;
int i=2;
{if (num == 2)
    return prime;
}
while(i<=num-1)
{
if(num%i==0)
{

return false;
}
i++;
}
if(i==num)

return prime;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow! Did you start with reading the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: Any chance that your source file is a `.c` instead of `.cpp` type? If yes, then change it and try again. If no, then please indicate the lines for which you are getting compilation errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn to format the code properly. Use code tags `{}` in the editor to format the code. Did you forgot to keep `;` at the end of prototype function in the header file ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to 'have a boolean function' (also known as 'return a boolean') you have to do two things. First, declare your function so that it know it'll return a boolean like this:

```
bool isPrime ( int num )
```

Then `return` a boolean value at the end of your function, like this:

```
return prime;
```

Now you can set something to equal the function, and it'll get the boolean back, like this:

```
x = isPrime(25);
```

`x` will be the boolean value `false` (assuming your prime code works correctly).

Comment: He/she is not returning a boolean value, but simply trying to print it.

Comment: I see that, but I believe it is only because they don't know how to return the value correctly.

Comment: Possibly, but at present they are having some other problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

According to your assignment

> isPrime is a function which takes an integer as a parameter and
>   returns true if the parameter is a prime number, and false otherwise.

So it must be declared as

```
bool isPrime( unsigned int n );
```

In the main you call it the similar way

```
std::cout << n << " is prime -> " << isPrime( n ) << std::endl;
```

So your function isPrime is wrong.

It could be defined the following way

```
bool isPrime( unsigned int n )
{
   bool prime = ( n == 2 ) || ( n % 2 && n != 1 );

   for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i * i < n; i += 2 )
   {
      prime = value % i != 0;
   }

   return prime;
}
```

I think that there is a sense to consider only non-negative values. Otherwise you should check inside the function whether the argument is positive or negative.

Comment: @Damien Black  I do not bother whether it is a homework or not.:) Sometimed it is more useful to see the code written by others than write it yourself.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I agree with Damien. At least you should use a [spoiler](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Comment: @Damien Black I really tried my best to know the answer of this question , so I create this account to find the right answer

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Thanl u soo much But I cant right it in my assignment like than because this is my second course in c++ and I didn't understand anything of your code could you please make it simple to me and I will write my code again in a different way thank alooot guys